# Preg replace symbols

Tags: preg-replace

Until now I was using str_replace to replace my letters to english letters, symbols to "-" etc., but now I discovered that there can be a lot of symbols and I don't know all of them..

So I don't know how my pattern should look like, but I need a function, which can replace all undefined symbols to "-".

It should allow only eng letters and numbers and after all it should replace where is two "-" into one. for example

> link-has--to-be-modern--as-i-said--
>
> link-has-to-be-modern-as-i-said

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$txt = trim(preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '-', $txt), '-');
```

[about character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)